# How do I do pattern matching against generic type when type parameter is unknown, but effectively not used?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I have a hierarchy of classes to simulate discriminated union. One such class is a record:

```
private sealed record ErrorStrWithEnum<TEnum>(string Error, TEnum Enum) : Error
            where TEnum : struct, Enum
```

then I have an object of type `Error` and I want to extract the message:

```
error switch
{
   ErrorStrWithEnum<_>(var message, _) => message
}
```

This obviously does not work. Even if classes supported covariance, I could not match against `ErrorStrWithEnum<object>(var message, _)` because cov-/contravariance is not supported for value types.

The alternative is to introduce intermediary type `ErrorStrWithEnum(string Error, object Enum)` but it will cause boxing.

Is there any more elegant alternative?

Comment: Really you should avoid switching on type in the first place (in general).  In this specific case, it looks like `Error` should have a message, not an error with an enum.  You shouldn't have to list out every possible type of error just to get the message from an error; even if your code compiled it would be undesirable.

Comment: @Servy it's a fixed set of types, so it's fine,

Comment: It's still a bad idea regardless of whether there are a fixed number or not.  It makes the code a maintenance nightmare as you now have a huge overhead for adding in new types of errors, which is likely to be a regular occurance.

Comment: @Servy the alternative of having `Result<TValue, TError>` is even worse. I'd better constrain the set of errors, so it's `Result<TValue>`. Well, actually there's [a dirty a hack](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/5317), how `TError` can stay not defined till the last moment.

Comment: You say the alternative is worse, and then just accept the answer suggesting functionally the same solution.  But anyway your explanation of why it's problematic is about code not shown, so while it looks like you are indeed doing something wrong, there isn't enough information to tell you what you should be doing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need introduce either a non-generic record with string for message or interface and match against that:

```
private record ErrorWithStr(string Error) : Error;
private sealed record ErrorStrWithEnum<TEnum>(string Error, TEnum Enum) : ErrorWithStr(Error)
        where TEnum : struct, Enum;
```

```
error switch
{
   ErrorWithStr(var message) => message
}
```

or

```
private interface IHaveError {
    string Error { get; }
}
private sealed record ErrorStrWithEnum<TEnum>(string Error, TEnum Enum) : Error, IHaveError 
    where TEnum : struct, Enum
```

```
x switch
{
    IHaveError  err=> err.Error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Records can implement interfaces, so you can expose that string as a interface property:

```
private interface IHasMessage {
    string Message { get; }
}

private sealed record ErrorStrWithEnum<TEnum>(string Message, TEnum Enum) 
    : Error, IHasMessage
    where TEnum : struct, Enum
{
    ...
}
```

Then you can match `IHasMessage`:

```
error switch
{
   IHasMessage { Message: var message } => message
}
```